# How to declare type object|void

Tags: typescript

I have the declaration

```
export interface IValidationError {
    valid: boolean;
    message: string;
}
export type ValErr = IValidationError | void;
```

And somewhere in the code

```
...
.filter(function(valErr:ValErr){
    return !valErr || valErr.valid;
});
```

The problem is that i've got error during compilation

```
error TS2339: Property 'valid' does not exist on type 'IValidationError | void'.
```

How to describe this type?

Answer (score 2):

You have to cast the object to the correct type and use duck-typing. The OR types in TypeScript don't meant that the object automatically implements both interfaces, it's just that it could be either type and the onus is on the developer to test it. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types and https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/discriminated-unions.html

```
.filter(function(valErr:ValErr){
    if (valErr && valError.hasOwnProperty("valid") ) {
        return (<IValidationError> !valErr).valid;
    }
    return true;
});
```

Comment: could you also use `instanceof`, instead of the property check?

Comment: @fiddles You can't use instanceof with an interface

Answer (score 0):

Below you can find the declaration of a void type variable:

```
let unusable: void = undefined;
```

You have to remember that declaring variables of type void is not useful because you can only assign undefined or null to them.

More information: 
[Basic Types in TS](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html)